# STM32 Eclipse (CubeIDE) debug project doesn't start in main.c, but in UcHeap assembly code instead

Tags: eclipse, arm, stm32, stm32f7

I have a working project, but from some point on, when I start it in Debug mode, it doesn't stop
in main.c, but stops in one point in the code before main...

Debugger reports trace/breakpopint at ucHeap() 0x20011b88 ....

If I click on Run->Reset, the projects resets correctly, in main.c or Reset_handler if I set additional breakpoint...

I've checked and cleared all breakpoints, but this still happens...

Obviously something happened, probably in project settings.
Where can I learn more about how exactly is project started and where to start checking what is wrong ?

Thanks in advance,
regards.

Comment: do you run code from the RAM? I syspect wrong bootx settings

Comment: Hi, thanks for response... It's simple embedded project, I guess the code is run from Flash...

Comment: *` trace/breakpopint at ucHeap() 0x20011b88 ....`* looks like SRAM for me

Comment: sorry, you're right... It's a FreeRTOS based project... Project probably runs something from RAM.  But what bugs me is why it gets there and why it stops at that address ?

Comment: it seems that ucHeap is basically heap space for FreeRTOS....

Comment: I know what it is.  you breakpoints are triggered when data is executed. Address shown shoes the address where breakpoint happened